# How to mount external HDD on 18.04? can't find in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I can see Elements HDD but it is not mounted.

```
My lsblk
sda                                                           
├─sda1 vfat              BBAE-8B0A                            /boot/efi
└─sda2 ext4              1df7cd45-1846-4e4b-a6da-172f020b6bc2 /
sdb                                                           
sdc                                                           
└─sdc1 ext4     main     773abc03-348b-4166-8e74-85c110c3983b 
sdd                                                           
└─sdd1 ntfs     Elements EE6426CE6426997B
```

fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 698,6 GiB, 750121910272 bytes, 1465081856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3ef4e255

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1465081855 1465079808 698,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

When I try to mount sdd1

```
sudo mount -t /dev/sdd1 /media/miki
```

I got

```
mount: /media/miki: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

I made mnt1,but now new errors occur

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdd1 /mnt1
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I gor bash: /media/miki: Is a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My HDD was corrupted .Solved it with ntfsfix

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdd1 was processed successfully.
```